# How to copy Active Directory from a production domain to a developer VM with Active Directory installed?

Tags: active-directory

We are developing some applications that require access to Active Directory, and may change some AD information.  What is the best way to copy the AD schema, users and groups to a second, separate AD so that developers may test their code without affecting production?  To clarify: the second domain has a different domain name:  COMPANY (production) and COMPANYDEV (dev)

Answer (score 2):

Keep the dev servers isolated from the production network, then restore a backup?

Comment: Bonus points for renaming the domain after restoring, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LDIFDE to export the production domain config, edit the exported text file if needed then import it to the development domain.